# Lets define boundaries for our site

Tags: discussion

There are many topics which are allowed to ask on Hinduism.SE but they could gather thousand's of questions in a similar pattern like:

- What was the age of Lord Hanuman?
- What was the age of Lord Ram?
- What was the age of Lord Ram when leaving Ayodhya?

and

- Was Lord Rama a vegetarian?
- Was Lord Hanuman a vegetarian?

..and so on

We can make such topics as a single post as a wiki and let other users edit the wiki answer. Doing so we can avoid further questions on these topics. This will let define boundaries for our site.

Please share what do you think about this and let also know other topics which you think might end up with thousands of questions in same pattern.

Comment: Asking for Book??? like this one? http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/any-good-books-about-shiva??

Comment: We should make wiki questions after we get ample of questions on a specific topic. Having 2 similar question isn't sufficient to start a wiki post for that particular topic.